# Delete/Discard the last data value from an Observable in RxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I got stuck in a situation where I need to discard or delete the last data from an Observable stream, been trying for a while but can’t seem to find a solution.
I know you can use Async Subject to get the last item but I actually need to do totally opposite of it. Any hints will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation, you can use [`Observable.skipLast()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#skipLast-int-) to solve that problem. It can take number of items to skip and produces `Observable`, that don't emits that particular number of **last** items.

More information you can find in [RxJava docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#skipLast(int)) and [reactive specification](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/skiplast.html)